# Check if Vue component extends another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 Vue components which one extends another:

```es6
var CompA = { ... }

var CompB = {
  extends: CompA,
  ...
}
```

I would like check programatically that CompB extends CompA, e.g.:

```es6
import CompA from './compA';
import CompB from './compB';

if (CompB instanceof CompA) {
  ...
}
```

This code raise the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vue components `CompA` and `CompB` are just plain JavaScript objects, there's no kind of subclassing or prototype chains here so `instanceof` won't work (not to mention `CompA` isn't a Vue instance so it wouldn't work anyway).

You'll have to write your own function to determine if one component extends another:

```js
function extendsComponent(Comp, Super) {
  while (Comp) {
    if (Comp === Super) {
      return true;
    }
    
    Comp = Comp.extends;
  }
  
  return false;
}

const A = {};
const B = { extends: A };
const C = { extends: B };

if (extendsComponent(C, A)) {
  console.log('C extends A (directly or indirectly)');
} else {
  console.log('C does not extend A');
}
```

If you are using `Vue.extend` to create your components, then you can use the prototype chain to check for inheritance as you normally would in JavaScript:

```js
const A = Vue.extend({});
const B = A.extend({});
const C = B.extend({});
const Z = Vue.extend({});

console.log(C.prototype instanceof A);  // true
console.log(C.prototype instanceof Z);  // false
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks - I had in mind that 'Vue.extend' and the 'extends' prop are equivalent